# how to find text string of variable length and replace with a fixed string text

Tags: string, windows, batch-file, find

I need to find a string in a `input.txt` file

```
Current Playback Device ID=2A99FA92-E624-4650-A032-DA719D9B03D5
```

and replace it with:

```
Current Playback Device ID=721D0FD1-DD46-11d0-8AAC-00A0C91D299F
```

BUT consider that the replace have to be also in the case that the original string - in this case `Current Playback Device ID=2A99FA92-E624-4650-A032-DA719D9B03D5` - contains different chatacters

**For Example**

```
Current Playback Device ID=AAAAAAAA-E624-AAAA-A032-AAAAAAAAAAAA
```

or

```
Current Playback Device ID=AAA2AAAAAAAAAAA
```

the string `"Current Playback Device ID="` is fixed
but the value after the `"="` can be different

In all the case the final result have to be

```
Current Playback Device ID=721D0FD1-DD46-11d0-8AAC-00A0C91D299F
```

How can I do?

Comment: Will all of these `Current Playback Device ID=` be at the start of a line and the line contains only `Current Playback Device ID=...whatever...` ?

Comment: What have you tried on your own so far? please share your code by editing the question and describe precisely what you have problems with...

Comment: yes yes whatever, and end with a blank space " "

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q36387900.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"
SET "replacementstring=721D0FD1-DD46-11d0-8AAC-00A0C91D299F"
(
FOR /f "usebackqtokens=1*delims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 FOR /f "delims==" %%x IN ("%%~a") DO (
  IF "%%x"=="Current Playback Device ID" (
   ECHO(%%x=%replacementstring%
  ) ELSE (ECHO(%%a
  )
 )
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q36387900.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Will remove empty lines.

Read each line. Tokenise the line read and assign any string before `=` to `%%x`. If that string matches the target string write out the starget + replacement string; otherwise simply regurgitate the line read.